# JQueryUI / SelectMenu - Unexpected padding on the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have the following `HTML` code which uses `JQuery`/`JQueryUI`.

I need to get rid of the `bottom padding` (red area) you can see on the attached image.

Here you have the corresponding `JSFiddle`:

https://jsfiddle.net/s8jmq2zh/

```js
$(function() {
  $("select").selectmenu();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color:#f00;">
      <select style="width:200px;">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Result:

[image]

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Maybe just delete the `background-color` prop?

Comment: Nop, that's only an indicator of the problem. The fragment code above is part of a very big code. I just simplified it to make it easy for you to understand what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra padding is because the jQueryUI stylesheet renders the `.ui-selectmenu-button` element as `display: inline-block` which adds some whitespace under the styled select menu. To fix this, override that style and set `display: block;`:

```js
$(function() {
  $("select").selectmenu();
});
```

```css
table .ui-selectmenu-button { display: block; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #f00;">
      <select style="width: 200px;">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fake select aka dropdown is `inline-block` element, so your space is just whitespace. If you set `display: block` for this fake input `ui-selectmenu-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all` it will remove unwanted space.

You can apply it by style like:

```
.td > .ui-selectmenu-button {
    display: block;
}
```

If this won't overwrite existing style, add `!important`.